# How to access PDF from headless chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, chromium, headless

I am trying to access a pdf from a headless chrome browser.

Below is the command I am trying to hit from the command prompt(Administrator). I can see the pdf file gets generated. However, I can not see any data coming up in the pdf.
The URL in the below command needs a password to access when I open it on the browser. It will really be a great help if you can let me know if I do need to use username, password (If yes then how and whats the command).Many thanks!!

```
"%chrome%" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="C:\Users\i077219\Desktop\temp3.pdf "https://**ipaddress**/s/opu/odata/sp/CA_OC_OUTPUT_REQUEST_SRV/Items(ApplObjectType='BILLING_DOCUMENT',ApplObjectId='0090004410',ItemId='1')/GetDocument/$value/
```